# Using GmailApp and CC more than 100 people

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, quota

I am using a free AppScript account, when I try to send a message using GmailApp and CC less than 100 people there is no problem, but more than 100 people get the message:
Exception: Limit Exceeded: Email Recipients Per Message.

```
function sendMail(fullname, mailTo, mailCC, subject, image) {
var img = DriveApp.getFileById(image).getAs("image/png");
var logo = {"logo" : img}
GmailApp.sendEmail(mailTo, subject, "", {
cc:     "nguyenvan1@gmail.com,nguyenvan2@gmail.com,nguyenvan3@gmail.com,nguyenvan4@gmail.com,nguyenvan5@gmai    l.com,nguyenvan6@gmail.com,nguyenvan7@gmail.com,nguyenvan8@gmail.com,nguyenvan9@gmail.com,nguyenvan1    0@gmail.com,nguyenvan11@gmail.com,nguyenvan12@gmail.com,nguyenvan13@gmail.com,nguyenvan14@gmail.com,nguyenvan15@gmail.com,nguyenvan16@gmail.com,nguyenvan17@gmail.com,nguyenvan18@gmail.com,nguyenvan19@gmail.com,nguyenvan20@gmail.com,nguyenvan21@gmail.com,nguyenvan22@gmail.com,nguyenvan23@gmail.com,nguyenvan24@gmail.com,nguyenvan25@gmail.com,nguyenvan26@gmail.com,nguyenvan27@gmail.com,nguyenvan28@gmail.com,nguyenvan29@gmail.com,nguyenvan30@gmail.com,nguyenvan31@gmail.com,nguyenvan32@gmail.com,nguyenvan33@gmail.com,nguyenvan34@gmail.com,nguyenvan35@gmail.com,nguyenvan36@gmail.com,nguyenvan37@gmail.com,nguyenvan38@gmail.com,nguyenvan39@gmail.com,nguyenvan40@gmail.com,nguyenvan41@gmail.com,nguyenvan42@gmail.com,nguyenvan43@gmail.com,nguyenvan44@gmail.com,nguyenvan45@gmail.com,nguyenvan46@gmail.com,nguyenvan47@gmail.com,nguyenvan48@gmail.com,nguyenvan49@gmail.com,nguyenvan50@gmail.com,nguyenvan51@gmail.com,nguyenvan52@gmail.com,nguyenvan53@gmail.com,nguyenvan54@gmail.com,nguyenvan55@gmail.com,nguyenvan56@gmail.com,nguyenvan57@gmail.com,nguyenvan58@gmail.com,nguyenvan59@gmail.com,nguyenvan60@gmail.com,nguyenvan61@gmail.com,nguyenvan62@gmail.com,nguyenvan63@gmail.com,nguyenvan64@gmail.com,nguyenvan65@gmail.com,nguyenvan66@gmail.com,nguyenvan67@gmail.com,nguyenvan68@gmail.com,nguyenvan69@gmail.com,nguyenvan70@gmail.com,nguyenvan71@gmail.com,nguyenvan72@gmail.com,nguyenvan73@gmail.com,nguyenvan74@gmail.com,nguyenvan75@gmail.com,nguyenvan76@gmail.com,nguyenvan77@gmail.com,nguyenvan78@gmail.com,nguyenvan79@gmail.com,nguyenvan80@gmail.com,nguyenvan81@gmail.com,nguyenvan82@gmail.com,nguyenvan83@gmail.com,nguyenvan84@gmail.com,nguyenvan85@gmail.com,nguyenvan86@gmail.com,nguyenvan87@gmail.com,nguyenvan88@gmail.com,nguyenvan89@gmail.com,nguyenvan90@gmail.com,nguyenvan91@gmail.com,nguyenvan92@gmail.com,nguyenvan93@gmail.com,nguyenvan94@gmail.com,nguyenvan95@gmail.com,nguyenvan96@gmail.com,nguyenvan97@gmail.com,nguyenvan98@gmail.com,nguyenvan99@gmail.com,nguyenvan100@gmail.com,nguyenvan101@gmail.com,nguyenvan102@gmail.com",
htmlBody: "<p>Hi " + fullname + "</p></br><img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="         + image + "'>"
```

});
}`

If I upgrade my account, this problem can be solved!

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation within gmail itself. its not something you can bypass

[Gmail sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

> 100 Recipients per message sent via SMTP (by POP or IMAP users) or the Gmail API
> Addresses in the To, Cc, and Bcc fields of a single email. Includes email sent using smtp-relay.gmail.com or smtp.gmail.com*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Send two emails one with the first 100 and another with the next?